# Working on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to push on my array different value , for example , I want a array like :

```
     array(2) { ["A056"]=> array(1) {   
                           [0]=> string(21) "User1name firstname " } 
                           [1]=> string(21) "User2name firstname " }    
                           [2]=> string(21) "User3name firstname " } 
                ["A057 etc..."]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "User1name firstname " } 
                                             [1]=> string(21) "User2name firstname " }    
                                             [2]=> string(21) "User3name firstname " }
```

All value need to be add on ["A056"] array .
It's a multidimensional array , how can I proceed ?? : 
My code is :

```
    for($i=0;$i<$arrLength-1;$i++){
      $arrayListeAgence= array($pieces[0]=> array($listUsers[$i]." ".$listUsers[$i+1]));
    }
```

Why I get only the last value (jean charles is the last value of my list) ?:

```
array(2) { ["A056"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Jean Charles " }
```

My pieces array like this :

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "A057" [1]=> string(108) "KEO/Micka/KIRAN/Maria/ATHISA/HIS/SURA/Beat/SPAR/Laura/DARTI/Sona/VANNINI/Priya" [2]=> string(6) "A058" [3]=> string(59) "KEO/Micka/KIRAN/MARIA/ATHISA/MAHIS/NICOLE/Laura" }
```

USERLIST array :(need to iterate and put value on the main array arrayListeAgence)

```
    $listUsers="";
    for($k = 1,$i=0; $k <sizeof($pieces); $k+=2){

        $listUsers [$k]= explode("/", $pieces[$k]);
    $i=$i+1;
    }
    print_r($listUsers);
```

output:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => KEO [1] => Micka [2] => KIRAN [3] => Maria [4] => MATHISA [5] => ATHISA [6] => SUDA [7] => Beat [8] => SPAR [9] => Laurence [10] => ARTTI [11] => Sona [12] => NaNINI [13] => Priya ) [3] => Array ( [0] => KEO [1] => Micka [2] => KIRAN [3] => Maria[4] => ATHISA [5] => ATHISA [6] => NICOLE [7] => Laura) )
```

Comment: Please show us the expected output. (Note: You can't have multiple keys with the same value!)

Comment: The expected output is :  '     array(2) { ["A056"]=> array(1) {   [0]=> string(21) "User1name firstname " } 
                                   [1]=> string(21) "User2name firstname " }    
                                   [2]=> string(21) "User3name firstname " }'  In other word, It's doesn't increment, all value is store on [0] why ?

Comment: @TheJoker post it in the question, not in comments ;)

Comment: What about the $listUsers array? Where are we supposed to get username and first name from?

Comment: @littleibex Ya I have a problem , how can I guess how many user in A058 , how I can iterate these user in my pieces array automatically ??

Comment: @TheJoker OK. Here's the thing. $arrayListeAgence is your final result. It's an array of A056, A057, A058, etc, each of which is an array of users (containing username and firstname). We have the $pieces array available in which A056, A057, A058 values are present alternatively. These will act as the keys of our desired array. However, for each of these, where are the usernames and firstnames? Are they present in a seperate array? Or are we supposed to extract it from $pieces values which are like "KEO/Micka/KIRAN/Maria/ATHISA/MAHIS/SURA/Beat/SPAR/Laura/DARTI/Sona/VANNINI/Priya".

Comment: @littleibex ya we are supposed to extract with explode function , for example KEO is username and Micka is firstname , see my code edit , how can iterate on the array of user, for example userList[1][2] give KIRN for A057 and userList[3][2] give KIRN also for A058.

Comment: @TheJoker I have updated my answer. Please check if it works for you and if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$pieces = array(
    "A057",
    "KEO/Micka/KIRAN/Maria/ATHISA/MAHIS/SURA/Beat/SPAR/Laura/DARTI/Sona/VANNINI/Priya",
    "A058",
    "KEO/Micka/KIRAN/MARIA/ATHISA/MAHIS/NICOLE/Laura"
);

$arrayListeAgence = array();
$usersAdded = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pieces); $i = $i + 2) {
    $key = $pieces[$i];
    $usersStr = $pieces[$i + 1];
    $users = explode('/', $usersStr);
    $arrayListeAgence[$key] = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($users); $j = $j + 2) {
        $username = $users[$j];
        if (array_search($username, $usersAdded) === false) {
            $arrayListeAgence[$key][] = $username . " " . $users[$j + 1] . " ";
            $usersAdded[] = $username;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arrayListeAgence);
```

Comment: In my case , I can Have multiple array , for example , A057,A058,.... , how can I generate It automatically??

Comment: For that we will need to know what your $listUsers and $pieces array look like

Comment: @littlebeix Thanks It's working , if you have an idea how can I find dupplicate value on A058 , for example KEO MIcka and KIRAN Maria are in A057 and A058, so I need to store dupplicate value and remove in A058 but keep on A057, how can I do this ?

Comment: @TheJoker I have updated my answer to avoid repetitions.

Comment: I have a little question if I got 3 agence (A057,A058 and A059) and user is on A058 and also on A059, how can I remove user from A059 and keep only on A058 ?

Comment: In case user is in A058 and A059 not in A057 , how can I keep user only in A058 , this code will be work ?

Comment: @TheJoker yeah, I understand. But that's what I am saying, the code already takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

In case `$arrayListeAgence` is your multi-dimensional array, this should produce the output you are looking for.

```
// Define the main array
$arrayListeAgence = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($pieces); $i += 2) {
    // Define one of the pieces
    $arrayListeAgence[$pieces[$i]] = [];

    for ($j = 1; $j < sizeof($listUsers); ++$j) {
        // Define a single element
        $arrayListeAgence[$pieces[$i]][] = $listUsers[$j - 1] . ' ' . $listUsers[$j];
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: http://ideone.com/gtYvIx

Comment: array(1) { ["A36"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Jean-Charles" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(19) " MARTIN" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "MN Dee" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "ne NOUAU" } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "mandi" } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "SANA" } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "KARSA" } } } , sorry  It's not what I expect :(

Comment: @TheJoker I have since modified the code and removed the extra (unnecessary) brackets - it should now produce the desired result.

Comment: It's near the expected output , but How can I autoIncrement the $pieces because It's not going to the next A057,A056,etc.... ??? why ?

Comment: It does increment. That is exactly what the outer loop is for. Your `$pieces` array may of course differ from the one I used. Please add it to your original question so we can take a look at it's structure.

Comment: check my edit for my piece array , you have A057 + userlist + A058+userlist (structure of my array)

Comment: I have changed the code to step 2 in the outer loop and also updated the Ideone example - it now uses a `$pieces` array just like yours.

Comment: @TheJoker Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it has resolved your issue so it can be "closed".